# Create Swagger API documentation for existing REST API in PHP application

Tags: php, swagger

I am trying to setup **Swagger API** documentation for my existing **REST API**. My application is developed in **PHP**.

I have installed **Swagger** and tried to configure same with the application.

I have given the URL ad `index.html` file, but it does not work.

Can someone help me to create the `swagger.json` and configure Swagger to display the initial documentation?

Comment: Could you please provide what are trying to do?

Comment: What you have try? post code

Comment: I have installed Swagger-UI Linux . In the index.html i have given application URL , which needs to be loaded :                                                                                                               
      window.onload = function() {
        const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
      url: "https://hostanme or applicationurl:8080/swagger-ui/docs/",
   </script>
   </body>
It does not load the application , Its display as unable to connect. Can you tell me where all i have to make changes/configure to create host the UI .

Comment: I have installed Swagger UI in my server and able to create a project & start the project. Project is available in local host. I want to edit the project to include documentation for my existing REST API. I have tried to open swagger editor, but nothing opens in the UI. Can someone tell how to open the swagger editor & update the documentation.